# Is it possible to connect to a Raven IIS instance as embedded?

Tags: ravendb

I have a RavenDB IIS instance that is working just fine via the Silverlight interface. I am trying to connect to as an embedded client by targeting the web folder, but I keep getting an error saying that it cannot find a lucene DLL. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible.  In embedded mode, the `EmbeddableDocumentStore` actually contains the database instance.  Only one can be spun up at a time. You cannot have multiple embedded clients using the same set of files.

If you have an instance running in IIS, then don't connect with embedded mode.  Connect using the regular client and point at the URL of your server.

Comment: Sweet thanks, I'm doing this on an installer, so it was easier to try and connect as embedded because I had all the paths already.